# Allow CORS in Spring-xd HTTP source

Tags: spring-xd

How do I configure HTTP source in Spring-xd to allow CORS? Setting the following in server.yml doesn't seem to help:

```
#Config to allow CORS
spring:
  profiles: admin
    xd:
      ui:
        allow_origin: "*"
```

Answer (score 0):

That setting is for the admin only.

The HTTP source is currently a very simple implementation using Netty; it does not use Spring MVC and does not support CORS.

It's intended for simple POST ingestion to a stream.

Comment: Any chance to have CORS support added to the HTTP source? We have customers on Windows and only know how to use browsers

Comment: I doubt it, in XD. However the http source in [spring-cloud-stream-modules](https://github.com/garyrussell/spring-cloud-stream-modules) is a full Spring MVC version so it could support CORS. These are stand-alone boot apps which are coordinated by spring-cloud-dataflow (the next generation of XD).